# Choosing different background color for divs on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have basic on click function that creates a draggable div with text appended to it. The second functionality that I have been to accomplish is to let the user choose a background color for the div. I am using a color picker plugin called [SPECTRUM](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#). The issue is that when choosing a new background color for a new div, the new background color is applied to previously created divs.  How can I keep adding new divs with different background colors? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/0wbnud4k/27/)

```
/** Colorpicker spectrum configuration **/
$("#colorpicker").spectrum({ //spectrum config
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    color: 'blanchedalmond',
    palette: [
        ["#000","#444","#666","#999","#ccc","#eee","#f3f3f3","#fff"]
    ],
    change: function(colorSelected) {
        color = colorSelected.toHexString();
    }

});

/** Add New Div with selected background **/
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent'
        }
    }).addClass('placement');

    $('.draggable').css('background-color' , color);
});
```

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li><textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Type text to append to div!"></textarea>
   </li>
<li><label>Choose Div Background Color:</label>
    <input type='text' id='colorpicker' /></li>
<li><input type="button" id="button" value="Create Draggable Div" />
    </li>
</ol>
<div>
    <div class="middle-side empty"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
$('.draggable').css('background-color' , color);
```

You are chaning the `background-color` of **all** your draggable elements, set it only to your new created element. Try this:

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent'
        }
    })
    .css('background-color' , color)
    .addClass('placement');
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/28/).

Comment: Oh that makes sense now. I was setting the background color for all. I will accept the answer once it lets me. thank you

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618453/changing-ul-background-color-on-button-click