# Changing <ul> background color on button click

Tags: jquery

On a button click I am creating a draggable div with the help of jquery ui. Each div created has text appended from a textarea input field. The text is placed in bulleted list tags. I am running into this problem: I want to set the background color dynamically for everything inside the `<ul>` tag. I am using [SPECTRUM](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) as the color picker. On the button click instead of changing the `<ul>` tag background it changes the whole div. How can I only change the `<ul>` background and not the div? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/0wbnud4k/50/)

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        html:  '<ul>'+
                '<li>'+
                '<a href="#">'+
                '</a>'+
                '</li>'+$('textarea').val()+'</li>'+
                '</ul>',
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent'
        }
    })
    .css('background-color' , color)
    .addClass('placement');
});
```

Comment: You can use any of the answers, but are you sure you want to put the textarea value inside 2 closing `</li>` tags?

Comment: @TomSarduy good call will change that. Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you're looking for something like this:
`html:'<ul><li><a href="#">' +$('textarea').val()+ '</a></li></ul>'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        html:  '<ul>'+
                '<li>'+
                '<a href="#">'+
                '</a>'+
                '</li>'+$('textarea').val()+'</li>'+
                '</ul>',
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent'
        }
    })
    .find('ul') //find ul then apply css
        .css('background-color' , color)
        .end() // to go back to select the previous div and apply addClass
    .addClass('placement');
});
```

Comment: **`+1`** I love the `end` method ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `style` attribute to the `ul` element, and remove `.css('background-color' , color)`. Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/53/).

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        html:  '<ul style="background-color: ' + color + '">'+
                '<li>'+
                '<a href="#">'+
                '</a>'+
                '</li>'+$('textarea').val()+'</li>'+
                '</ul>',
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent'
        }
    })
    .addClass('placement');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should apply `background-color` to your `ul`, not the whole `div`:

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        html:  '<ul>'+
                '<li>'+
                '<a href="#">'+
                '</a>'+
                '</li>'+$('textarea').val()+'</li>'+
                '</ul>',
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent'
        }
    })
    .addClass('placement')
    .find('ul').css('background-color' , color);
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/52/).